# USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 powered hub

Tags: usb, wireless

I'm looking for a USB hub, and learned that [USB3.0 has an interference problem with 2.4GHz devices](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html) such as routers (though I don't care that much, because I have a dual-band router) and wireless mice (which I do care about, because that's how Logitech mice work).

Are there mixed USB 3.0 + 2.0 hubs other than [this one, which has power problems](https://www.amazon.com/review/RIW21U51G492W)?

And do mixed hubs solve this interference problem if I connect the 2.4GHz device into a 2.0 port of the hub?

(My encounter with the interference was that I had my Logitech mouse plugged in, and when I plugged in a Google Pixel phone, the mouse started stuttering massively.)